# Magento insert data into database through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, magento

I'm new to ajax so I'm not sure if i'm approaching this correctly, basically I have a variable in javascript that need to be inserted into the database, this is what I have so far...

```
onInit: function() {
    window.fcWidget.on('widget:loaded', function() {
        window.fcWidget.user.get().then(function(resp) {
            var status = resp && resp.status,
            data = resp && resp.data;
            if (status === 200) {
                if (data.restoreId) {
                    // Update restoreId in  database

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "insert.php",
                        data: data.restoreId, 
                        success: function(data) { alert("Success"); },
                        failure: function(data) { alert("Failure"); }

                    })

                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I have placed the file "insert.php" in the same folder but it seem like it doesn't get called at all...

This is what insert.php looks like

```
<?php
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){

        if(isset($_POST['data.restoreId']){
            $restoreId =$_POST['data.restoreId'];
        }

        $first = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
        $last = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getLastname();

        $fullName = $first . "." . $last;

        //get resource model
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        //retrieve write connection
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        //read connection
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

        $exId = $fullName;
        $resId = $restoreId;

        $testQuery = "SELECT `externalId` FROM `freshchat_user` WHERE `restoreId` = '$fullName'";

        $result = $readConnection->fetchAll($testQuery);

        if(count($result) == '0'){
            $query = "INSERT INTO `freshchat_user`(`externalId`, `restoreId`) VALUES ('$exId','$resId')";
            $writeConnection->query($query);
        }else{
            //echo "nope";
        }
    }
?>
```

I checked the network tab but insert.php doesn't seem to be called at all, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your js snippet is an unexplainable mess. Debug it and see if it comes to ajax request at all. insert.php should be a controller if you put this in context of magento.

Comment: The problem with this is it's not mine... I'm trying to integrate freshchat into my magento site and this is the code they gave me.

Answer (score 0):

//Please put your insert.php file in root path(Magento installation path) and change below line in your javascript code.

```
url: "www.yourwebsite.com/insert.php",
```

Comment: Ok try to run this path in browser www.yourwebsite.com/insert.php and check this file called. If working then your ajax code is not triggering this file. Also copy paste this path in your ajax code and try once again.

Comment: Yeah it's not loading the file when I go to the URL... is this a permission thing?